# Push Reactjs app to Heroku giving fsevents error

Tags: node.js, macos, reactjs, heroku, fsevents

I am following the steps as mentioned in https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration and am able to create the project. But when I try to push the project, it gives me `fsevents` error. Its a completely fresh project.

1. I have added `node_modules` in `.gitignore`
2. I have tried `npm i -f` as given in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13935
3. I have tried adding `fsevents` to `optionalDependencies` as said in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8551

Non of these have helped me. The error I get :

```
Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
remote:        npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3:     wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
remote:        npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
remote:        npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
remote:        npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
remote:        npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.y1nYC/_logs/2018-04-09T15_10_24_227Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

My `package.json` is as follows

```
{
  "name": "my_site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: interesting, same thing is happening to me

Answer (score 3):

My build was successfull after adding the following scripts in package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm i -f",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
}
```

Comment: this is applies laravel/vue js

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the package-lock.json file in the react/client folder worked for me. I think the package-lock.json contains system-specific settings and the same settings don't work on the Heroku server.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my packages to `react 16.5` resolved this for me (ran `npm update` and committed changes)